Getting requirements to build wheel
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [40 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\elisa\Desktop\try\try1\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\elisa\Desktop\try\try1\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\elisa\Desktop\try\try1\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\elisa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-x2elmy6z\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 332, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=[])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\elisa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-x2elmy6z\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 302, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\elisa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-x2elmy6z\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 318, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\elisa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-x2elmy6z\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 117, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\elisa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-x2elmy6z\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 145, in setup
          _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\elisa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-x2elmy6z\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 283, in __init__
          _Distribution.__init__(self, dist_attrs)
        File "C:\Users\elisa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-x2elmy6z\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 279, in __init__
          self.finalize_options()
        File "C:\Users\elisa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-x2elmy6z\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 635, in finalize_options
          ep(self)
        File "C:\Users\elisa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-x2elmy6z\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools_scm\_integration\setuptools.py", line 123, in infer_version
          _assign_version(dist, config)
        File "C:\Users\elisa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-x2elmy6z\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools_scm\_integration\setuptools.py", line 58, in _assign_version
          _version_missing(config)
        File "C:\Users\elisa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-x2elmy6z\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools_scm\_get_version_impl.py", line 117, in _version_missing
          raise LookupError(
      LookupError: setuptools-scm was unable to detect version for C:\Users\elisa\Desktop\try\try1.      

      Make sure you're either building from a fully intact git repository or PyPI tarballs. Most other sources (such as GitHub's tarballs, a git checkout without the .git folder) don't contain the necessary metadata and will not work.

      For example, if you're using pip, instead of https://github.com/user/proj/archive/master.zip use git+https://github.com/user/proj.git#egg=proj
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

Help me with this, i was trying to "pip install ..."

Did you try to upgrade pip ? pip install --upgrade pip. Which package are you trying to install ?

You'll need to tell us what exactly you're trying to pip install .... The issue here is that something is getting built from source, which (a) shouldn't be necessary (b) is failing.

Have you tried upgrading setuptools? pip install setuptools --upgrade

i also once had the same problem. mine fixed like this. pip install --upgrade wheel this should help
